# Updating a network graph in Bokeh

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, bokeh, interactive

I try to get a network graph displayed with an input field, and when validating the input, refresh the graph with data updated according to this input.
However, what I obtain is that the graph will be blank after the update.
I tried to this example https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html?highlight=event%20button#single-module-format
But it seems that updating datasource is not enough with graph.
Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import networkx as nx

from bokeh.plotting import figure, from_networkx, curdoc
from bokeh.models import Rect, HoverTool,  TextInput
from bokeh.layouts import column

global graph
G = nx.Graph()

field = TextInput(value="first", title="Graph to select: ")

def graphe(base, H):
    for i in range(0,10):
        H.add_node(base+str(i), {'name':base+str(i),
                            'version': str(i),
                            'width': .2,
                            'offset':- 25,
                             'color': ' red'})
        H.add_edge(base +str(0), base+str(i))

def update(attr, old, new):
    newG = nx.Graph()
    graphe("second", newG)
    newgraph = from_networkx(newG, nx.spring_layout, scale=4, center=(0,0))
    graph.node_renderer.data_source.data = dict(newgraph.node_renderer.data_source.data)
    graph.edge_renderer.data_source.data = dict(newgraph.edge_renderer.data_source.data)
    graph.node_renderer.glyph = Rect(height=0.1, width="width", fill_color="color")

graphe("first", G)
plot = figure(title="RPM network", width= 1500, height= 800, x_range=(-2.1, 2.1), y_range=(-2.1, 2.1),
              tools="", toolbar_location=None)

hover = HoverTool()
hover.tooltips = """
<div style=padding=5px>@name</div>
<div style=padding=5px>@version</div>
"""
plot.add_tools(hover)
graph = from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout, scale=4, center=(0,0))
graph.node_renderer.glyph = Rect(height=0.1, width="width", fill_color="color")
plot.renderers.append(graph)
field.on_change('value', update)

curdoc().add_root(column(field, plot))
```

Instead of updating datasource, I tried also to build a new graph with the same global variable `graph`, but in this cas, the graph is not updated.
What I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution that is working.
In the update procedure, a new plot is build in the same way as the first. At end, the member of the children of the layout is replaced with the new plot.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import networkx as nx

from bokeh.plotting import figure, from_networkx, curdoc
from bokeh.models import Rect, HoverTool,  TextInput
from bokeh.layouts import column

global graph
G = nx.Graph()

field = TextInput(value="first", title="Graph to select: ")

def graphe(base, H):
    for i in range(0,10):
        H.add_node(base+str(i), {'name':base+str(i),
                            'version': str(i),
                            'width': .2,
                            'offset':- 25,
                             'color': ' red'})
        H.add_edge(base +str(0), base+str(i))

def update(attr, old, new):
    newG = nx.Graph()
    graphe(new, newG)
    newplot = figure(title="RPM network", width= 1500, height= 800, x_range=(-2.1, 2.1), y_range=(-2.1, 2.1),
              tools="", toolbar_location=None)
    newgraph = from_networkx(newG, nx.spring_layout, scale=4, center=(0,0))
    newgraph.node_renderer.glyph = Rect(height=0.1, width="width", fill_color="color")
    newplot.add_tools(hover)
    newplot.renderers.append(newgraph)
    layout.children[1] = newplot

graphe("first", G)
plot = figure(title="RPM network", width= 1500, height= 800, x_range=(-2.1, 2.1), y_range=(-2.1, 2.1),
              tools="", toolbar_location=None)

hover = HoverTool()
hover.tooltips = """
<div style=padding=5px>@name</div>
<div style=padding=5px>@version</div>
"""
plot.add_tools(hover)
graph = from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout, scale=4, center=(0,0))
graph.node_renderer.glyph = Rect(height=0.1, width="width", fill_color="color")
plot.renderers.append(graph)
field.on_change('value', update)

layout = column(field, plot)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```